# android.view.InflateException can't remove

Tags: java, android, xml

i always get exception when i try to run the no actionbar with moving image

log

```
07-20 20:38:32.393: D/dalvikvm(13148): Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-20 20:38:32.538: E/Trace(13148): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-20 20:38:32.713: D/AbsListView(13148): Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-20 20:38:32.738: D/AndroidRuntime(13148): Shutting down VM
07-20 20:38:32.738: W/dalvikvm(13148): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40edf2a0)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{example.example.actionbar/example.example.actionbar.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class example.example.actionbar
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class example.example.actionbar
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at example.example.actionbar.Main.onCreate(Main.java:49)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    ... 11 more
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.example.actionbar
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
07-20 20:38:32.743: E/AndroidRuntime(13148):    ... 22 more
```

AlphaForegroundColorSpan.java

```
package example.example.actionbar;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;

public class AlphaForegroundColorSpan extends ForegroundColorSpan {

private float mAlpha;

public AlphaForegroundColorSpan(int color) {
    super(color);
}

public AlphaForegroundColorSpan(Parcel src) {
    super(src);
    mAlpha = src.readFloat();
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    dest.writeFloat(mAlpha);
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    ds.setColor(getAlphaColor());
}

public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
    mAlpha = alpha;
}

public float getAlpha() {
    return mAlpha;
}

private int getAlphaColor() {
    int foregroundColor = getForegroundColor();
    return Color.argb((int) (mAlpha * 255), Color.red(foregroundColor), Color.green(foregroundColor), Color.blue(foregroundColor));
}
}
```

KenBurnsView.java

```
package example.example.actionbar;


import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;

/**
* Created by f.laurent on 21/11/13.
 */
public class KenBurnsView extends FrameLayout {

private static final String TAG = "KenBurnsView";

private final Handler mHandler;
private int[] mResourceIds;
private ImageView[] mImageViews;
private int mActiveImageIndex = -1;

private final Random random = new Random();
private int mSwapMs = 10000;
private int mFadeInOutMs = 400;

private float maxScaleFactor = 1.5F;
private float minScaleFactor = 1.2F;

private Runnable mSwapImageRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        swapImage();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mSwapImageRunnable, mSwapMs - mFadeInOutMs*2);
    }
};

public KenBurnsView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public KenBurnsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public KenBurnsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mHandler = new Handler();
}

public void setResourceIds(int... resourceIds) {
    mResourceIds = resourceIds;
    fillImageViews();
}

private void swapImage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "swapImage active=" + mActiveImageIndex);
    if(mActiveImageIndex == -1) {
        mActiveImageIndex = 1;
        animate(mImageViews[mActiveImageIndex]);
        return;
    }

    int inactiveIndex = mActiveImageIndex;
    mActiveImageIndex = (1 + mActiveImageIndex) % mImageViews.length;
    Log.d(TAG, "new active=" + mActiveImageIndex);

    final ImageView activeImageView = mImageViews[mActiveImageIndex];
    activeImageView.setAlpha(0.0f);
    ImageView inactiveImageView = mImageViews[inactiveIndex];

    animate(activeImageView);

    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.setDuration(mFadeInOutMs);
    animatorSet.playTogether(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(inactiveImageView, "alpha", 1.0f, 0.0f),
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(activeImageView, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f)
    );
    animatorSet.start();
}

private void start(View view, long duration, float fromScale, float toScale, float fromTranslationX, float fromTranslationY, float toTranslationX, float toTranslationY) {
    view.setScaleX(fromScale);
    view.setScaleY(fromScale);
    view.setTranslationX(fromTranslationX);
    view.setTranslationY(fromTranslationY);
    ViewPropertyAnimator propertyAnimator = view.animate().translationX(toTranslationX).translationY(toTranslationY).scaleX(toScale).scaleY(toScale).setDuration(duration);
    propertyAnimator.start();
    Log.d(TAG, "starting Ken Burns animation " + propertyAnimator);
}

private float pickScale() {
    return this.minScaleFactor + this.random.nextFloat() * (this.maxScaleFactor - this.minScaleFactor);
}

private float pickTranslation(int value, float ratio) {
    return value * (ratio - 1.0f) * (this.random.nextFloat() - 0.5f);
}

public void animate(View view) {
    float fromScale = pickScale();
    float toScale = pickScale();
    float fromTranslationX = pickTranslation(view.getWidth(), fromScale);
    float fromTranslationY = pickTranslation(view.getHeight(), fromScale);
    float toTranslationX = pickTranslation(view.getWidth(), toScale);
    float toTranslationY = pickTranslation(view.getHeight(), toScale);
    start(view, this.mSwapMs, fromScale, toScale, fromTranslationX, fromTranslationY, toTranslationX, toTranslationY);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    startKenBurnsAnimation();
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mSwapImageRunnable);
}

private void startKenBurnsAnimation() {
    mHandler.post(mSwapImageRunnable);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_kenburns, this);

    mImageViews = new ImageView[2];
    mImageViews[0] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image0);
    mImageViews[1] = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
}

private void fillImageViews() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mImageViews.length; i++) {
        mImageViews[i].setImageResource(mResourceIds[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Main.java

```
package example.example.actionbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Main extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "NoBoringActionBarActivity";
private int mActionBarTitleColor;
private int mActionBarHeight;
private int mHeaderHeight;
private int mMinHeaderTranslation;
private ListView mListView;
private KenBurnsView mHeaderPicture;
private ImageView mHeaderLogo;
private View mHeader;
private View mPlaceHolderView;
private AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator mSmoothInterpolator;

private RectF mRect1 = new RectF();
private RectF mRect2 = new RectF();

private AlphaForegroundColorSpan mAlphaForegroundColorSpan;
private SpannableString mSpannableString;

private TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mSmoothInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    mHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);
    mMinHeaderTranslation = -mHeaderHeight + getActionBarHeight();

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mHeader = findViewById(R.id.header);
    mHeaderPicture = (KenBurnsView) findViewById(R.id.header_picture);
    mHeaderPicture.setResourceIds(R.drawable.picture0, R.drawable.picture1);
    mHeaderLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header_logo);

    mActionBarTitleColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar_title_color);

    mSpannableString = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.noboringactionbar_title));
    mAlphaForegroundColorSpan = new AlphaForegroundColorSpan(mActionBarTitleColor);

    setupActionBar();
    setupListView();
}
private void setupListView() {
    ArrayList<String> FAKES = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        FAKES.add("entry " + i);
    }
    mPlaceHolderView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_header_placeholder, mListView, false);
    mListView.addHeaderView(mPlaceHolderView);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FAKES));
    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int scrollY = getScrollY();
            //sticky actionbar
            mHeader.setTranslationY(Math.max(-scrollY, mMinHeaderTranslation));
            //header_logo --> actionbar icon
            float ratio = clamp(mHeader.getTranslationY() / mMinHeaderTranslation, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            interpolate(mHeaderLogo, getActionBarIconView(), mSmoothInterpolator.getInterpolation(ratio));
            //actionbar title alpha
            //getActionBarTitleView().setAlpha(clamp(5.0F * ratio - 4.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F));
            //---------------------------------
            //better way thanks to @cyrilmottier
            setTitleAlpha(clamp(5.0F * ratio - 4.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F));
        }
    });
}

private void setTitleAlpha(float alpha) {
    mAlphaForegroundColorSpan.setAlpha(alpha);
    mSpannableString.setSpan(mAlphaForegroundColorSpan, 0, mSpannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    getActionBar().setTitle(mSpannableString);
}

public static float clamp(float value, float min, float max) {
    return Math.max(min,Math.min(value, max));
}

private void interpolate(View view1, View view2, float interpolation) {
    getOnScreenRect(mRect1, view1);
    getOnScreenRect(mRect2, view2);

    float scaleX = 1.0F + interpolation * (mRect2.width() / mRect1.width() - 1.0F);
    float scaleY = 1.0F + interpolation * (mRect2.height() / mRect1.height() - 1.0F);
    float translationX = 0.5F * (interpolation * (mRect2.left + mRect2.right - mRect1.left - mRect1.right));
    float translationY = 0.5F * (interpolation * (mRect2.top + mRect2.bottom - mRect1.top - mRect1.bottom));

    view1.setTranslationX(translationX);
    view1.setTranslationY(translationY - mHeader.getTranslationY());
    view1.setScaleX(scaleX);
    view1.setScaleY(scaleY);
}

private RectF getOnScreenRect(RectF rect, View view) {
    rect.set(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
    return rect;
}

public int getScrollY() {
    View c = mListView.getChildAt(0);
    if (c == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int firstVisiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int top = c.getTop();

    int headerHeight = 0;
    if (firstVisiblePosition >= 1) {
        headerHeight = mPlaceHolderView.getHeight();
    }

    return -top + firstVisiblePosition * c.getHeight() + headerHeight;
}

private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_transparent);

    //getActionBarTitleView().setAlpha(0f);
}

private ImageView getActionBarIconView() {
    return (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
}

/*private TextView getActionBarTitleView() {
    int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
    return (TextView) findViewById(id);
}*/

public int getActionBarHeight() {
    if (mActionBarHeight != 0) {
        return mActionBarHeight;
    }
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);
    mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(mTypedValue.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    return mActionBarHeight;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

ParallaxImageView.java

```
package example.example.actionbar;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;  
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by f.laurent on 21/11/13.
 * antoine-merle.com inspiration
 */
public class ParallaxImageView extends ImageView {

private int mCurrentTranslation;

public ParallaxImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ParallaxImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ParallaxImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)     {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setCurrentTranslation(int currentTranslation) {
    mCurrentTranslation = currentTranslation;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, -mCurrentTranslation / 2)  ;
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NoBoringActionBarActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height">

    <example.example.actionbar
        android:id="@+id/header_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/picture0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/header_logo_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_logo_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_header_logo" />

</FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

view_header_placeholder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

view_kenburns.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image0"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Style-v14.xml

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">homeAsUp|showHome|showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in your xml

```
  <example.example.actionbar
    android:id="@+id/header_picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/picture0" />
```

where

`<example.example.actionbar` is a package of your project. If you want to use custom view in your xml you have to specify the full qualified path to the class. E.g

```
<example.example.actionbar.ParallaxImageView
    android:id="@+id/header_picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/picture0" />
```